# How can I utilize JAX library on my code with numpy take realted error: "NotImplementedError: The 'raise' mode to jnp.take is not supported."

Tags: jax

Due to my need to speed up my written code, I have modified that to **pure NumPy** code to evaluate the runtime in this way and by JAX accelerator in Python. I don't know if my code is appropriate to be accelerated by JAX, but my little previous studies and JAX usage experiences encourage me to try vectorizing or parallelizing the prepared NumPy code by JAX. For initial test, I have put `jax.jit` decorator on the function, but it stuck at the first line of my code. it raised the following error in Colab:

```
<__array_function__ internals> in take(*args, **kwargs)

UnfilteredStackTrace: NotImplementedError: The 'raise' mode to jnp.take is not supported.

The stack trace below excludes JAX-internal frames.
The preceding is the original exception that occurred, unmodified.

--------------------

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<__array_function__ internals> in take(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/jax/_src/numpy/lax_numpy.py in _take(a, indices, axis, out, mode)
   5437   elif mode == "raise":
   5438     # TODO(phawkins): we have no way to report out of bounds errors yet.
-> 5439     raise NotImplementedError("The 'raise' mode to jnp.take is not supported.")
   5440   elif mode == "wrap":
   5441     indices = mod(indices, _constant_like(indices, a.shape[axis_idx]))

NotImplementedError: The 'raise' mode to jnp.take is not supported.
```

I don't know how to handle this code by JAX. This error is related to `np.take` module, although I guess it will stuck again at some other lines e.g. which contain `reduce`.
The sample code is:

```
import numpy as np
import jax


pp_ = np.array([[0.75, 0.5, 0.5], [15, 10, 15], [0.5, 3., 0.35], [15, 17, 15]])
rr_ = np.array([1, 3, 2, 5], dtype=np.float64)
gg_ = np.array([-0.48305741, -1])
ee_ = np.array([[0, 2], [1, 3]], dtype=np.int64)


@jax.jit
def JAX_acc(pp_, rr_, gg_, ee_):

    rr_act = np.take(rr_, ee_)
    r_add = np.add.reduce(rr_act, axis=1)
    pc_dis = np.sum((r_add, gg_), axis=0)
    ang_ = np.arccos((rr_act ** 5 + pc_dis[:, None] ** 2) / 1e5)
    pl_rad = rr_act * np.cos(ang_)
    pp_act = np.take(pp_, ee_, axis=0)
    pc_vec = -np.subtract.reduce(pp_act, axis=1)
    pc_ = pp_act[:, 0, :] + pc_vec / np.linalg.norm(pc_vec, axis=1)[:, None] * np.abs(pl_rad[:, 0][:, None])
    return print(pc_dis, pc_, pl_rad)


JAX_acc(pp_, rr_, gg_, ee_)
```

**main Qusestion:** Could JAX library be utilized for this example? How?
Shall I use other modules instead `np.take`?
I would be appreciated for helping to cure this code by JAX.
*---------------- solved by the update ----------------*

---

***I would be grateful for any other explanations on the following extraneus questions (not needed):**

Which of math operations `(-,+,*,...)` and their NumPy equivalents `(np.power, nu.sum,...)` will be faster using JAX? Do NumPy ones will be handled by JAX in a better scheme (in terms of speed) than common math ones?

Does JAX CPU mode need other writing styles than TPU mode; I didn't use that so far.*

---

**Updates:**
I have changed the code using `jnp` related modules based on @jakedvp comment and the problem by `np.take` is gone:

```
def JAX_acc_jnp(pp_, rr_, gg_, ee_):

    rr_act = jnp.take(rr_, ee_)
    r_add = jnp.sum(rr_act, axis=1)  # .squees()
    pc_dis = jnp.add(r_add, gg_)
    ang_ = jnp.arccos((rr_act ** 5 + pc_dis[:, None] ** 2) / 1e5)
    pl_rad = rr_act * jnp.cos(ang_)
    pp_act = jnp.take(pp_, ee_, axis=0)
    pc_vec = jnp.diff(pp_act, axis=1).squeeze()
    pc_ = pp_act[:, 0, :] + pc_vec / jnp.linalg.norm(pc_vec, axis=1)[:, None] * jnp.abs(pl_rad[:, 0][:, None])
    return pc_dis, pc_, pl_rad
```

For `pc_dis` and `pc_` the results are true, but `pl_rad` is different due to `ang_` different achieved values which are all `-1.0927847e-10`; perhaps because true values are with `-13` decimals and JAX changed dtype to float32, I don't know. If so, how could I specify which dtype JAX use?

[image]

***larger data sizes:*** [pp_](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H5icD9IfLsre5cXnRMQdTBWomfAUMIoo/view?usp=sharing), [rr_](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bnpUa7d6UdAZ_x9yx-l3BXebq_JULscp/view?usp=sharing), [gg_](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12tn3N6XmqHYGEiklQ7tN3Atyj8gAZ9W0/view?usp=sharing), [ee_](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bRHtUpkRYCtrT9tqnYcMmrFH3Cy4v660/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your error appears to come from JAX, but your example code does not use JAX. Can you clarify what code you’re running when you see this error?

Comment: @jakevdp I have used `@jax.jit` above the function, I edit the code. Please check.

Comment: In general, `jax.jit` is not compatible with `numpy` operations. You should try `import jax.numpy as jnp`, and then write your function with `jnp` instead of `np`. You can find a good introduction to JAX in its tutorial: https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax-101/index.html

Comment: @jakevdp Thanks for the point. I have modified the code using `jnp` and updated the above issue. I have tested by larger data size and get the mentioned error, which seems to be related to the `jnp.arccos` or `dtype` that JAX used. Data are in `np.float64` format but JAX seems convert them to `float32`?? Does it? By ex small data sample, results are true, but with changing `1e5` to e.g `1e11` in `ang_ ` equation, the results differ. I prepared a link to my larger data sizes if it be needed. I have used `squeeze()` instead of `reduce`, does JAX have such `jnp.ufunc.reduce` or must use `reduce`?

Comment: @jakevdp Does it need something like *signature*s in *numba* that precompile the function and determine input and output formats. I am asking this due to the aforementioned `float32` related problem and because sometimes (almost, just, in the first run in my Colab tests) I have got `The slowest run took 31.34 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.` when I am testing the speed by `%timeit`; This warning will be disappeared by *signature* specifications in *numba* before the function jitting.

Comment: Regarding 64-bit values, see https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#double-64bit-precision. Regarding benchmarking JAX, see https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#benchmarking-jax-code